# when i close modal and open that modal again google map is not loading in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

I am working on google map, i am loading this google map in bootstrap modal, right now i have dyanamic list and there is button to view google map in bootstrap modal, but this is working first time only, when i close the modal and trying to open that again, google map is loading, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? here is my code for that

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map_canvas  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }
    #map_canvas {
    width : 770px;
    height : 400px;
    }
</style>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDESxPrtya1459HVTiokw-zjaZkmgaGhe8"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     * Use bindTo to allow dynamic drag of markers to refresh poly.
     */

    function MVCArrayBinder(mvcArray) {
        this.array_ = mvcArray;
    }
    MVCArrayBinder.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    MVCArrayBinder.prototype.get = function (key) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
            return this.array_.getAt(parseInt(key));
        } else {
            this.array_.get(key);
        }
    }
    MVCArrayBinder.prototype.set = function (key, val) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
            this.array_.setAt(parseInt(key), val);
        } else {
            this.array_.set(key, val);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
     * @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
     */
    function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(event.latLng);
        var len = path.getLength();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            title: '#' + len,
            map: map,
            //draggable: true
        });
        marker.bindTo('position', poly.binder, (len - 1).toString());
    }


    var poly;
    var map;

    function initialize(locations_map, address_latlong) {
        //alert('dsdsd');
        var latlong = address_latlong.split('-');
        var polyOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3, map: map
        };
        poly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latlong[0], latlong[1]),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                //mapTypeIds: ['satellite', 'nearmap']
                mapTypeIds: ['satellite']
            },
        });

        var locations = locations_map;

        poly.binder = new MVCArrayBinder(poly.getPath());
        var arr_data = new Array();
    //alert(locations.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var evt = {};
            evt.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
        //console.log(evt.latLng);
        bounds.extend(evt.latLng);
        addLatLng(evt);
        }



        poly.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
        });

    }



    function show_modal_map(id) {
        get_map_data(id);
    }

    function load_modal(locations_map, address_latlong) {
        jQuery('#mapModal').modal({ 
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        }).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            jQuery(".modal-backdrop").attr('style', 'display:none;');
            jQuery(".modal-backdrop").removeClass('fade');
            jQuery(".modal-backdrop").removeClass('show');
            initialize(locations_map, address_latlong);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            var latlong = address_latlong.split('-');
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong[0], latlong[1]);
            map.setCenter(center);
        }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
        //alert('sdsd');
        jQuery("#map_canvas").html('');
    });
    }

    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //var center = new google.maps.LatLng(10.9386, -84.888);
    });

    function get_map_data(quote_id) {
//alert('sdsdsd');
        var data = {};
        data.id = quote_id;
        data.action = 'WCP_Quote_Controller::get_map_data';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                var address_latlong = response.address_latlong;
                var locations_map = new Array();
                var markers_data = response.markers_latlong_data;
                if (markers_data != '') {
                    var count = 1;
                    var markers = markers_data.split('#');
                    for (var n = 0; n < markers.length; n++) {
                        var lat_long_data = markers[n].split('*');
                        locations_map.push([lat_long_data[0], lat_long_data[1], count]);
                        count++;
                    }
                    //locations_map.push([lat_long_data[0], lat_long_data[1], count]);
                }
                console.log('Get Locations');
                console.log(locations_map);
                load_modal(locations_map, address_latlong);
            }
        });
    }

    /*jQuery("#mapModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    alert('sdsd');
    jQuery("#map_canvas").html('');
    });*/

</script> 
<!--    <div id="map_canvas"></div>-->
<div id="mapModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" style="width: auto !important;height: 500px !important;"> <!-- style="width: auto !important;height: 500px !important;" --->
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <!--        <h4 class="modal-title">Map</h4>-->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        </div>
<!--        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>-->
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it necessary that you destroy the map on close of the modal ? whats `jQuery("#map_canvas").html('');` for ?

Comment: When i close the modal i removing google map data

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik previous `jQuery("#map_canvas").html('');` i was not doing this, but to load google map again i did this for test purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Map api V3, setPosition/setCenter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875472/google-map-api-v3-setposition-setcenter-is-not-working)